# Apply filter to JSON.parse() dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following js:

```
var text = '{"firstName" : "abc", "lastName" : "def", "age" : 25}';
obj = JSON.parse(text).firstName;
console.log(obj);
```

This prints the value corresponding to the key firstName as expected. However what I am trying to do is, I want to store the key to be fetched in a variable and use it along with JSON.parse() statement. Something like this:

```
var text = '{"firstName" : "abc", "lastName" : "def", "age" : 25}';
var filter = 'firstName';
obj = JSON.parse(text).filter;
console.log(filter)
console.log(obj);
```

This code prints 'undefined' onto the console. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
obj = JSON.parse(text).filter;
```

to

```
obj = JSON.parse(text)[filter];
```

There are two ways to access properties: dot notation and bracket notation.

```
var test = object.property;  //(dot notation)
var test = object[property_name]; //(bracket notation)
```

The issue you are facing is that you are trying to access a property called 'filter' on your object which does not exists and therefore undefined.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to access a value with a key stored in a variable, you need to use the square brackets notation.

`obj.key` is equivalent to `obj['key']`, but `var x = 'key'; obj.x` is not equal to `obj.key`.

**Open your console and run this code snippet**

```js
var text = '{"firstName" : "abc", "lastName" : "def", "age" : 25}';
var filter = 'firstName';
obj = JSON.parse(text)[filter];

console.log(filter);
console.log(obj);
```

A simple example

```
var obj    = { a: 'A' },
    filter = 'a';

console.log( obj.a );       // outputs 'A'
console.log( obj['a'] );    // outputs 'A'
console.log( obj[filter] ); // outputs 'A'
console.log( obj.filter );  // outputs undefined, obj does not have a 'filter' property
```

Comment: I answered first but no problem ;)

Comment: @Anvith Blex did get in there about a second before me

Comment: @Magrangs Nothing to worry about, your answer is perfect and got my +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

this is trying to access an attribute called `filter` from the parsed JSON which doesn't exist and is therefore `undefined`.

Instead you want `JSON.parse(text)[filter]`